# arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXMethodExecutor

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I am getting following information in console when the test is executed by arquillian.

Apr 15, 2014 7:41:56 PM org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXMethodExecutor invoke
SEVERE:Failed:com.bidis.bridge.systemlog.server.facade.SystemLogTest.testInsertSystemLog1
Apr 15, 2014 7:41:56 PM org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.jmx.JMXMethodExecutor invoke
SEVERE:Failed:com.bidis.bridge.systemlog.server.facade.SystemLogTest.testInsertSystemLog
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.272 sec - in com.bidis.bridge.systemlog.server.facade.SystemLogTest

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

The test are green. But, one of the test which is suppose to insert record in db is also green, but no records are inserted in DB.

I am not able to figure out what is happing here. Why the SEVER: Failed message is there after JMX invoke.?

Any input on this.

Thank you
Sanjeev.

Comment: You'll need to share some of your code.  Did you start a transaction and commit it?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue. It was a bug in Arquillian 1.1.4 and it's fixed in [1.1.5](http://arquillian.org/blog/2014/06/25/arquillian-core-1-1-5-Final). Simply updating helped us.